# How can I reinsert every row in a table in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I added a new identity column, and I need to update it so that the id column goes into the identity column, then delete the old id column and rename the identity column, because you cannot change a column to an identity.

I don't know how to do this, I guess I want to loop through each row, insert it into the same table, setting the identity field to match the id field (using IDENTITY_INSERT) but I am not familiar with loops in SQL. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with temp table something like this:

Sample table and data

```
create table xx
(
  OldID int
)

insert into xx values(10),(20),(30)
```

Add NewID as identity and get the value from OldID.

```
create table xxTmp
(
  OldID int,
  [NewID] int identity
)

set identity_insert xxTmp on

insert into xxTmp(OldID, [NewID])
select OldID, OldID
from xx

set identity_insert xxTmp off

drop table xx
exec sp_rename 'xxTmp', 'xx'
```

Comment: Because it's an identity column, it can only be set using INSERT.

Comment: @SLC - Of course. Added another way that **might** work for you. You need to drop and recreate any FK constraints since the table is deleted.

Comment: It is also possible to change your OldID column to be identity. Have a look at [this article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/61979/) at SQL Server Central.

Comment: Getting there, although I am getting an error saying `IDENTITY_INSERT is already ON for table '...xx'` when I am trying to set it for xxTmp. This makes no sense, as if I try to disable it it says you can't as xx has no identity column. Any ideas?

Comment: @SQL - Nope. You should do the identity insert toggle for the temp table and the temp table should have the identity column defined.

Comment: Cheers it was just a glitch with sql server, I reconnected and it went away... almost there now! :)